# npm -g "whatever" too many open files

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I know sometimes you can get the "Too many open files" error by updating or installing big npm packages but right now it is happening to me anytime i try to do something with "-g"

```
npm -g ls
npm ls -g
npm update -g
```

even specifically

```
npm update -g grunt-cli
npm update -g [whatever package]
npm install -g [whatever package]
```

i'm on a Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
and my ulimit is already set to `unlimited`

any suggestion?

Comment: try to use the command ulimit -n 2048. Which node version you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using MacOSX, try to find out what is your limit by doing:

`launchctl limit maxfiles`

I have a clean install of OSX Maverick and I have:

`maxfiles    256            unlimited`

If your system does not show that, try to edit/create a `/etc/launchd.conf` with something like:

`limit maxfiles 256 unlimited`

** Increase 256 to a higher number if that does not helps.  Remember to reboot.

Check out this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks